# how to allow VMs and host ping each other?

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, virtualization, hadoop

I'm trying to set up a few VMs of ubuntu on my windows 7 machine. I need the machines to be able to ping each other and I would like to assign them a `FQDN`.

The purpose of this project is to set up a hadoop cluster. I'm following the instructions [here](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.0/bk_using_Ambari_book/content/ambari-chap1-4.html).

> The fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for each host in your system,
>   and which component(s) you wish to set up on which host. The Ambari
>   install wizard does not support using IP addresses. You can use
>   hostname -f to check for the FQDN if you do not know it.

I've edited `/etc/hosts` :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.0.0.1 base.localdomain base
```

**How can I assign FQDN to each VM, and make sure the machines can see each other?** I'm using virtualbox.

I do not have DNS. My VirtualBox is set up as NAT and all defaults.

Comment: This is partly a Windows and VirtualBox networking specific question. I'm not sure whether Ask Ubuntu is the right place for this. Either way - VirtualBox offers many different type of virtual networking. Please include your current configuration in your question to start with. Also: do you have a central DNS server running? Or do you want to set it up in `/etc/hosts` files on each and every machine?

Comment: @qert thanks so much for your response. i dont have dns and not planning to get one. the virtualbox is all defaults NAT. i plan to do etc/hosts on every machine

Comment: @qertvdijk is there any other info that i can provide to you that could be useful?

Comment: I could answer your question perfectly fine if I would have a Windows PC here (that's why this is the wrong site to ask). NAT networking in VirtualBox is isolated connectivity to the outside world - you'd probably want to add a network of the other types.

Comment: In NAT mode, the virtual machine can ping the host at 10.0.2.2, but AFAIK the host cannot ping the vm.

Answer (score 11):

Change **NAT** to **Internal Network** :

- Select your VM
- then press **Setting**
- then **Network**.

Now you can see adapter attached to your VMs , to make all machine able to ping each other select **Internal Network**, that make a connection between all VMs , to ping the computer host select **Bridge Adapter** , then select the interface.

Comment: thanks! what settings need to be changed in /etc/hosts etc?

Answer (score 1):

In case some people are interested in VirtualBox, and this is what I think:

```
VBoxManage.exe modifyvm vm-name --memory 1024 --nic1 nat --nic2 hostonly --hostonlyadapter2 "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter"
```

nic1 with nat is for Internet access;
nic2 with hostonly is for host access;
check virtual machine host name in `/etc/sysconfig/network` or using `hostnamectl set-hostname host-name`
and file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-[interface]
DEVICE=interface
HWADDR=some string...
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=0e5413f5-asdf-40e1-b0fb-asdfasdfasdfasdf
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.57.104
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

I configured virtual machine using virtualbox command tool, but from time to time, the generated files are corrupted, so I have to fix above files manually.

Then in the host: ensure the nic with a name "`VirtualBox Host-Only Network`" is configured in the same network (`IP4: 192.168.57.1, NETMASK=255.255.255.0`). And that "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" is created when install VirtualBox (or is it?).

please correct this if any flaw.